# I have read Prelude To Foundation, will I miss much if i skip the Forward The Foundation?

Tags: suggested-order, foundation

I have read the Prelude To Foundation on my phone and I want to continue reading the Foundation Series. The problem is that I can't find a book version of Forward The Foundation, so i'll also have to read it on the phone, but reading on phone is really tiring and probably not healthy for eyes, so I want to skip the second prequel and follow straight from the main series. Will I miss much? I wanted to read the plot,but I don't want to get spoiled.

Comment: That's the one book in the series I haven't read. But being that it was the last one published (even though it is the second of seven chronologically) I would think the disruption would be minimal.

Answer (score 5):

If your plan is to read the remaining Asimov books (Foundation, Foundation and Empire, Second Foundation, Foundation's Edge, and Foundation and Earth) you won't miss anything at all. Forward the Foundation was written last, and is largely a character story about Hari Seldon. It isn't needed to understand any of the events that were written before it.

If your intention is to read the Second Foundation trilogy by Bear and Brin (ignore Benford's entry; Foundation's Fear never happened) then Forward the Foundation is helpful.

If your intention is to just read good books, read Forward the Foundation. It's the best one Asimov wrote, for my money.

Comment: My personal opinion was that *Forward* was at least better than *Prelude*. I wasn't thrilled with *Prelude*, and definitely liked *Forward*. If that helps.